Qt Application becomes unresponsive on handling high frequency data coming from UDP socket
I have a Qt Application which works on high frequency data, I am receiving data of around 2kb every 30ms, but what happens is the application becomes unresponsive.
#ifndef UDPHANDLER_H
#define UDPHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QThread>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

class UdpSocketHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit UdpSocketHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~UdpSocketHandler();
    void bindSocket(const QHostAddress &address, quint16 port);

public slots:
    void onReadyRead();  // Slot to handle the datagrams

private:
    QUdpSocket *udpSocket;
    QThread *workerThread;  // Thread for the UDP handling
    QElapsedTimer Elapsed_time;

};

#endif // UDPHANDLER_H

#include "udphandler.h"
#include "custom/data/DataFile.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QTimer>

UdpSocketHandler::UdpSocketHandler(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), udpSocket(nullptr), workerThread(new QThread(this))
{
}

void UdpSocketHandler::setupThread()
{
    this->moveToThread(workerThread);

    connect(workerThread, &QThread::started, this, &UdpSocketHandler::setupSocket);

    workerThread->start();  
}

UdpSocketHandler::~UdpSocketHandler()
{
    if (workerThread->isRunning()) {
        workerThread->quit();
        workerThread->wait();
    }

    if (udpSocket) {
        udpSocket->close();
        delete udpSocket;
        udpSocket = nullptr;
    }

    delete workerThread;
}

void UdpSocketHandler::setupSocket()
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);   
    udpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::ReceiveBufferSizeSocketOption, 64 * 1024);  
    udpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption, 1);

    if (udpSocket->bind(address, port, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint)) {
        qWarning() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Socket bound to Addr:" << address.toString() << "PORT:" << port;

        connect(udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &UdpSocketHandler::onReadyRead);
    } else {
        qWarning() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Failed to bind UDP socket. Addr:" << address.toString() << "PORT:" << port;
    }
}

void UdpSocketHandler::bindSocket(const QHostAddress &m_address, quint16 m_port)
{
    address = m_address;
    port = m_port;

    setupThread();
}

void UdpSocketHandler::onReadyRead()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());

        QtConcurrent::run([datagram]() {
            aerx::readDataFromStruct(datagram); 
        });
        datagram.clear();  
    }
}

//In main.cpp
UdpSocketHandler* udpHandler = new UdpSocketHandler();
udpHandler->bindSocket(QHostAddress(offsetSenderIP), offsetSenderPORT);


Note that the problem is with udp connection only, if i update data from while loop "without UDP connection" everything works as expected but updating same thing through udp connection makes whole application unresponsive
    connect(timerForTest, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this](){
        aerx::setMapVal(KEY_PitchVal, pitch);
        aerx::setMapVal(KEY_YawVal,   yaw);
        aerx::setMapVal(KEY_RollVal,  roll);

        pitch += i_pitch;
        yaw   += i_yaw;
        roll  += i_roll;

        if(pitch >= 90 || pitch <= -90)
            i_pitch *= -1;
        if(yaw >= 180 && yaw <= -180)
            i_yaw *= -1;
        if(roll >= 50 || roll <= -50)
            i_roll *= -1;
    });

     //timerForTest->start(33); /* uncomment this, to test smoothness of PFD UI update without data coming from simulator */


Your worker thread is not doing anything useful. Your UdpSocketHandler still lives on the main thread and your direct connection is forcing all datagrams to be handled on the main thread. Use QObject::moveToThread on the UdpSocketHandler to move if to the worker thread too.

It really improved, but improved only not  fixed.

Same goes for your QThread::started callback: the lambda executes on the main thread (because you passed this as received, which lives on the main thread), therefore your QUdpSocket is on the main thread, therefore your main thread is constantly dispatching messages to your worker thread. You need to be very careful and/or explicit on where stuff lives and executes in Qt.

Note: if you're spinning up a separate thread anyway that would be woken up 30+times per second , you might as well block in a loop on socket->receiveDatagram()..

?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Your moveToThread does nothing because you have a parent specified. Object will always live in the parent's thread.
